# How to open Google map pointing to Address that is specified in TextBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a multiline `TextBox` which contains the Address. Now, I want to Open a Google Map pointing to the address that is specified in `Address TextBox` on button click same as in `OutLook` in WPF Windows application. **On button click it must open the GoogleMap/Bing Map and locate the address in Browser**. Any Idea?

Comment: maybe this will help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238551/WPF-Map-App-WPF-meets-Google-Geocoding-Static-Maps

Answer (score 0):

To do this using Bing Maps you simply need to create the correct URL to the Bing Maps site and open it from code. You can find documentation on how to create URL's to the Bing Maps site here: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-gb/bing/ff808440.aspx